# VB.Net WebSite Get Assembly Version

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, assemblyinfo

We have a very old legacy VB.Net ASPX WebSite, not Web App, and I am trying to implement simple versioning.  Either auto increment or manual as it doesn't matter.

So far I have tried putting the AssemblyInfo.vb file in the root folder and in the App_Code folder.

Then i have tried various implementations of the following;

```
Dim versionNumber As Version
versionNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

This only ever return 0.0.0.0.

I have also used;

```
Dim a As String = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Business.EmailHelper)).GetName().Version.ToString()
```

The latter gets me a version as I am targeting a class library that has AssemblyInfo.vb in it.

I just can't seem to get the same for the WebSite.

Where do I place the AssemblyInfo.vb file in the WebSite so that I can read the version information?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to version your website or class in your ASPX WebSite ?

Answer (score 0):

To version the assembly for an ASP.Net Website project you need to [precompile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx) it. You also need to include the AssemblyInfo.vb either via a Page directive or the Web.config file. MSDN article on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228042.aspx).